# git post-receive checkout to remote machine?

Tags: linux, git, bash, rsync

If you add the following script as a `hooks/post-receive` hook to a bare git repository `foo.git`:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/bar git checkout -f
```

then whenever someone pushes to the repository the current state will be updated in directory `bar`.

This requires `bar` and `foo.git` to be on the same machine.

What's the easiest way to modify it so that the checkout is made on a remote machine (say `baz:/bar`) ?

One way would be to:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/tmp/bar git checkout -f
rsync ... /tmp/bar baz:/bar
```

Is there a better way?  Perhaps not requiring an intermediate temp directory?  (If not what are the correct options to pass to rsync such that the resulting directory is indentical to being checked out directly?)

Comment: Does the remote machine also have git installed, or are you just working with the files?

Comment: @Duotrigesimal: Ideally the remote machine shouldn't have to have git installed.  The checkout should just be a plain checkout of the current tree (no `.git` dir), as it is locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GIT_WORK_TREE=/bar` means that `bar` is a git repo.

If `bar` is a git repo on the remote side, then it can pull from a bare repo `bare_bar.git` (also on the remote side), to which you can push to.

In other words, your `post-receive` hook would push to bare_bar repo through ssh, and a `post-receive` hook on that bare repo would trigger the pull from the actual repo `bar`: see "[Creating a git repository from a production folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11724354/6309)".

---

> I'd prefer a solution that keeps the remote server free of any .git dirs (and even the git package itself ideally)

In that case, your current post-receive hook and its `rsync` command seems to be the only way to *incrementally* copy new data to a remote working tree.

- [`git archive`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive) would archive everything each time.
- [`git bundle`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle) would require git on the other side.

Comment: No, `bar` is a "plain" working tree, it doesn't have a `.git` dir in it.  (The `GIT_WORK_TREE` variable tells git the location of the working tree to use in the context of the command.)  Therefore `bar` cannot pull or push to `foo.git`.

Comment: @user1131467 could you make it a git repo though? Is there git on the remote server.

Comment: That's worth considering, sure - but I'd prefer a solution that keeps the remote server free of any `.git` dirs (and even the git package itself ideally).

Comment: @user1131467 in that case, your current solution seems optimal. I have edited my answer to include that.